# Impossible to create Jar from Modules in a Kotlin project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, jar, jvm

I'm trying to create Jar from Modules for a Kotlin project using IntelliJ, but it's impossible to choose the Main.kt, any suggestions about it?

[Pic of the problem, I can't embedded images right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyXpt.png)

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Ideally, you could add the image directly, instead of a link, since links can change over time. It also turns your question more readable.

Comment: You could add the Main.kt in a companion in another class with @JvmStatic on it to access it. However I think you should extract what you need from that main into a class and import that class.